# can't install dotnetnuke on windows 8

Tags: dotnetnuke

After following the tutorial steps from this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kOoQJDeTlJ0

and clicking on the final button to visit newly created website, I get the following error:

http://dnndev.me/Default.aspx?tabid=59&error=Object+reference+not+set+to+an+instance+of+an+object.&content=0

I have tried it several times, and also tried following steps from some other tutorials, but the error would persist. However when I tried to install it on different computer, it worked just fine.

I found possible solution here:

[Dotnetnuke Site settings PageLoadException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091288/dotnetnuke-site-settings-pageloadexception-object-reference-not-set-to-an-insta)

but I just don't know how to access that stored procedure that he metioned as I am new to dnn.

Can anybody help me with this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by looking at the EventLog and Exceptions table in the database to see if you can get a more detailed error.

```
select * from eventlog order by logcreatedate desc

Select * from exceptions
```

Did you do anything else, such as create a module project, before you ran through the installation process with DNN?